# CSS Friendly Control Adapters causes security error?

Tags: asp.net, css, visual-studio-2008, security, configuration

I just added a reference to the CSS Friendly Control Adapters dll and added the following file (CSSFriendlyAdapters.browser) to my "App_Browsers" folder:

```
<browsers>
  <browser refID="Default">
    <controlAdapters>
      <adapter controlType="System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeView"
               adapterType="CSSFriendly.TreeViewAdapter" />
    </controlAdapters>
  </browser>

  <browser id="W3C_Validator" parentID="default">
    <identification>
      <userAgent match="^W3C_Validator" />
    </identification>
    <capabilities>
      <capability name="browser"              value="W3C Validator" />
      <capability name="ecmaScriptVersion"    value="1.2" />
      <capability name="javascript"           value="true" />
      <capability name="supportsCss"          value="true" />
      <capability name="supportsCallback"     value="true" />
      <capability name="tables"               value="true" />
      <capability name="tagWriter"            value="System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter" />
      <capability name="w3cdomversion"        value="1.0" />
    </capabilities>
  </browser>
</browsers>
```

Now when I try to run any portion of my site, I get the following error:

- The application attempted to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy.  To grant this application the required permission please contact your system administrator or change the application's trust level in the configuration file.

Any ideas?

Comment: doesn't surprise me *at all* - the CFAs are an unholy abomination of a quickfix patch for a disease

Comment: I have never heard anything that bad about them- I used them on a project in VS2005 and they seemed OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this [link](http://cssfriendly.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=19533)

The only fix is to remove all trust level settings in the web.config